#  web.config backslash appears twice Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2010

I have an asp.net web application that I made in Visual Studio 2008.  Everything worked just fine until I switched to VS 2010.  When that happened, I started seeing some weird behavior with my database connection string.  The string (edited, but format is the same) is as follows:

```
<add name="DBname" connectionString="Data Source=SomeText\SomeMoreText;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The problem is with the SomeText\SomeMoreText part.
When I run this in the debugger, the '\' is changed into '\\'.  This breaks everything.

My question, which probably has an extremely simple answer is this:
How can I get VS2010 to treat the connection string like a normal string without trying to insert the extra slash?

Comment: its because of escape sequence try adding @ symbol before getting string.

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? When you view the ConnectionString in the debugger, it's showing the value escaped, hence the double \\. What is the error you are receiving.

Comment: I've never experienced that as an issue; I use \ with no problems.  But if you are using C# and finding this in the debugger, it does replace \ with \\, if looking as a string.  Take a look at a file path, for testing purposes, in the immediate window, do:  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, and it will return a path like c:\\users\\name\\documents\\etc

Comment: @Blake was right.  The debugger showed the escaped \, but it wasn't really in the connection string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extra slash is not there as far as interpretation of the string is concerned. It is merely an escape character '\' before the slash '\'.

Want proof? Add the following to your code (with proper naming of course):

```
Debug.WriteLine(connectionStringValueHere);
```

Here is a small app:

```
        string test = "This\\is\\a\\test";

        Console.WriteLine(test);
        Debug.WriteLine(test);

        Console.Read();
```

Note that the string, in both console and debug (output window) is This\is\a\test. If you do the following in the immediate window when the code is at a breakpoint:

```
 ? test
```

You see the following output

```
? test
"This\\is\\a\\test"
```

But you have the escapes present, which is normal for strings in .NET.

Comment: That pesky debugger.  That means something else is wrong (probably a db permission hiding somewhere), but this issue never really existed.

Comment: It could be a db permission, but may not be at the actual server level. What type of application is this (web or windows? etc)? Data source with a slash suggests an instance other than default, so what version of SQL Server (or maybe SQL Server Express). There are a lot of routes to examine. Figuring out where the bomb is is important. Have you set up profiler and seen what this looks like from SQL Server's side?

Comment: I figured it out.  It was something dumb that really doesn't add anything to this discussion.

Comment: One cool thing about the human brain is it often finds the answer just moments after you post to a forum. That tends to be what I find to be true. It has something to do with release of stress once you have other people looking at things. Good you found the answer.