# serialize object to json .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have to serialize object to json string. This is my code:

```
                var addData = new {
                    nick = user.UserName,
                    imie = user.Firstname,
                    nazwisko = user.Surname,
                    wojewodztwo = user.State

                };

                var tempUser = new
                {
                    email = user.Email,
                    list = "12212",

                    state = 1,
                    confirm = 0,
                    custom_fields = addData

                };

              (...)

               var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

               PostData = serializer.Serialize(tempUser);
```

This is result:

> "{\"email\":\"testowy@aa.pl\",\"list\":\"12212\",\"state\":1,\"confirm\":0,\"custom_fields\":{\"nick\":\"JakisNicvk\",\"imie\":\"Marian\",\"nazwisko\":\"Mariański\",\"wojewodztwo\":\"małopolskie\"}}"

It looks awfull. How can I generate json string like this, without `\`? (and where main object has array with `custom_fields`)?

> {"email":"22@aa.pl","list":"12212","custom_fields":{"personalization_tag_1":"value
>   1","personalization_tag_2":"value 2"}}

Regards.

Comment: Your string is correct. Just use the magnifier icon to see the unescaped string while debugging.

Comment: I4V's right. The string is only escaped in the debugger. If you write it to a file/database/etc it will appear correctly (or use the magnifier icon).

Comment: possible duplicate of [web.config backslash appears twice Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570894/web-config-backslash-appears-twice-visual-studio-2010)